# Multiple select options in one row

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a select field, with the multiple tag. Right now, the field has many options, so I don't like the idea that all options are below each other. What I am trying to achieve, is to have more options in each row, to make the select field much smaller, and easier to navigate in. This is what the select field looks like now:

```
[option]
[option]
[option]
[option]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
[option] [option] [option] [option]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (relatively) simple solution that emulates a select element. I've written it in jQuery but it could be done in pure JS as well.

In my demo the elements are floated two per row but obviously this could be changed easily.

[Here is the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/acXWx/14/)

**Edit:** Missed that it's a multiple select. Here is an [updated multiple select version.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/acXWx/18/)

Comment: Actually, I use Chrome, and all your options are beneath one another.

Comment: It's just an alignment thing, obviously didn't have time to make this pixel perfect cross-browser. Lower the width of `#options li` and they will float. Also edited my solution to include a multiple select version.

Comment: I changed the width, and it now works. Width was too long for 1px :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't float, or otherwise move, `option` elements with CSS or, so far as I'm aware, JavaScript. While this is impossible, why not instead use a nested `ol` (or `ul`...) to contain the elements that you want to display horizontally? For example:

```
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select some stuff</legend>
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <li><label for="inputs1">label 1</label><input type="checkbox" name="inputs[]" id="inputs1" /></li>
            <li><label for="inputs2">label 2</label><input type="checkbox" name="inputs[]" id="inputs2" /></li>

<!-- other stuff -->

                <li><label for="inputs11">label 11</label><input type="checkbox" name="inputs[]" id="inputs11" /></li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

With the CSS:

```
fieldset {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
}

fieldset > fieldset {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    display: none;
}

fieldset:hover > fieldset,
fieldset > fieldset:hover {
    display: block;
}

fieldset > fieldset > ol li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.2em;
    width: 6em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LkMTZ/2/).

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid using checkboxes. Those make the validation much harder, as there are like 160 options :)

Comment: Unfortunately you're pretty much tied to a similar approach, unless you're prepared to have a *very* long `select` element...have you considered posting a question about your validation problems?

Comment: I would not like to write a new article because of that, but the problem I would have are those checkboxes. I'd have to check how many of them are selected, because there is a limit of max 4 selected items at a time. Next I'd have to populate an array with the data, and then send it to the script for validation via AJAX. Not only that, but I also have more than one select fields, so that's a extremely long code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the native `select` HTML control.

You could instead write some javascript code to create an element, such as a `span` for each option, and append it to the page. These would then sit horizontally across from each other. You would then hide the original `select` element, but hook up the events on the appended divs to highlight the relevant option of the select on click.

Comment: is there an example somewhere on the internet?